# Calculating The sum of SandPiles

Tags: python

I am a noob in python
Well i watched a video from numberphile (https://youtu.be/1MtEUErz7Gg)
that was about sandpiles (adding them) so i decided to write my own python program to add 2 sandpiles.
but for some reason it does not work
The program gives me the wrong sum like 2+2=7 type wrong

it should give me:

> [ [2, 2, 0], [2, 1, 1], [0, 1, 3] ] +  [ [2, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [3, 1, 0] ] = 
>   [[2, 1, 0],[0, 3, 3],[1, 2, 3] ]

but instead gives:

> [ [2, 2, 0], [2, 1, 1], [0, 1, 3] ] +  [ [2, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [3, 1, 0] ] =
>   [[1, 3, 3], [0, 1, 2], [2, 2, 3]]

This is my code

```
X  = [ [2, 2, 0], [2, 1, 1], [0, 1, 3] ]
Y  = [ [2, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [3, 1, 0] ]
xy = [ [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0] ] 

i = j = 0

while (i < 3):  
    while(j < 3):
        xy[i][j] = X[i][j] + Y[i][j]
        j = j + 1
    i = i + 1
    j = 0

def get_above(pile):
    found = False
    while not found:
        i, j = 0,0
        while (i < 3):
                while (j < 3):
                    if(pile[i][j] > 3):
                       return i, j  
                    j = j + 1            
                i = i + 1
                j = 0
        found = True        

    return True            


def tupple_pile():

    while get_above(xy):
        i, j = get_above(xy)
        neg = [ [i, j+1], [i+1, j], [i, j-1], [i-1,j] ]
        neg = [n for n in neg if n[0] in [0, 1, 2] and n [1] in [0, 1, 2]]
        k = 0
        while k < len(neg):
            p = neg[k][0]
            q = neg[k][1]
            xy[p][q] = xy[p][q] + 1
            k = k + 1

        xy[i][j] = xy[i][j] - 4

    return xy       

tupple_pile()
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? How have you tried to solve it? :)

Comment: Be much more specific as to what is not working. State the expected results, the actual results, and any traceback you got as an error. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please first state the problem you aim to solve. We don't know what you mean by *adding* sandpiles. Given a problem statement.

Comment: Tip: You can loop with `for i in [1, 2, 3]:` instead of looping with `while`. IMO that kind of code is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You really should be more specific in your question. Running your code as it is results in Errors.

Anyhow, one thing that looks strange is the check function. Is it supposed to filter out indices that are outside the sandpile? In that case I think you will see something missing here:

```
if (neg[i][j] < 0) or (neg[i][j]):
```

Try with this instead:

```
if (neg[i][j] < 0) or (neg[i][j] > 2):
```

The second problem with this loop is that you are deleting elements from neg `del(neg[i])` while iterating over it. This is error prone. And as you may have noticed, as soon as you delete an item, the `i` will go out of range.

A better way to filter a list is to use a list comprehension, something like this:

```
neighbors = [ [i, j+1], [i+1, j], [i, j-1], [i-1,j] ]
neighbors = [n for n in neighbours if n[0] in [0, 1, 2] and n[1] in [0, 1, 2]]
```

Comment: Yeah The check function was suppose to filter out indices that were outside the pile anyway thanks